# Find all Products that contain specific multiple Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I want to find Products that have a specific set of tags only.

E.g: an array with two or more ids: [1, 2] 
and return only products that have those two tags.

I've used `Product.includes(:tags).where('tags.id' => [64, 65]).all` but this returns any products containing *either* of these tags.

Here is are my models:

```
# models/product.rb
has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, through: :taggings

# models/tag.rb
has_many :taggings
has_many :products, through: :taggings

# models/tagging.rb
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :tag
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `tag_ids = [64, 65]`, perhaps do something like:

```
tag_ids.each_with_object(Product.includes(:tags)) do |tag_id, query_base|
  query_base.where('tags.id' => tag_id)
end
```

I believe that should `and` your `where`s and give you `products` that have all the specified `tags`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this still seems to return the same sort of thing. :/

Comment: It returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` that includes `Product`s that have `tag` with `id` *either* `64` *or* `65`? Hm...